# Test Active Record Callback without hitting database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, callback

```
class Book  < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :author
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :publisher
  has_many   :books
end  

class Publisher < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy :remove_empty_author
  has_many   :authors, dependent: destroy_all

  def remove_empty_author
    books_present = authors.map(&:book).all? { |book| book.present? }
    authors.destroy_all unless books_present
  end
end

class PublishersController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    @publisher = Publisher.find(params[:id].to_i)
    @publisher.destroy # for simplicity I only show the destroy call
  end
end
```

#### Scenario

This is so close to working!
I have a controller test.
I want to test the following without creating a database entry or querying the database:
1. The remove_empty_author call back is called & if I delete it & the before_destroy the test complains.
2. Destroy is called on author.

Note:
I do not want to test the details of the remove_empty_author method. This will be tested in a model unit test delete a publisher and all of the authors only if the author has no books.

#### What I have tried

```
describe "#delete," do
  context "Publisher has no authors," do
    before do
     author = mock_model("Author", book: [])
     @publisher = Publisher.new(id: 2, authors: [author, author])
     current_publisher = mock_model("Publisher", id: 1)
     allow(Publisher).to receive(:find).and_return(@publisher)
     allow(controller).to receive(:current_publisher).and_return(current_publisher)
    end

    it "Controller calls destroy on Publisher" do
      expect_any_instance_of(Publisher).to receive(:destroy)
    end

    it "Publisher calls remove_empty_author" do
      expect_any_instance_of(Author).to receive(:destroy)
      @publisher.run_callbacks(:destroy) do
        false # Prevent active record from proceeding with destroy
      end
    end 
  end
 end
```

#### Things that are working

1. Controller calls destroy on publisher test works.
2. The test successfully enters the remove_empty_author call back where
   `books_present = false`,
   `authors = [(Double "Author_1001"), (Double "Author_1001")]`    `authors.destroy_all = []`

#### Error I am trying to overcome

`Failure/Error: 
  DEFAULT_FAILURE_NOTIFIER = lambda { |failure, _opts| raise failure }
 Exactly one instance should have received the following message(s) but didn't: destroy`

#### What is not working

`expect_any_instance_of(Author).to receive(:destroy)`

Comment: Hey, just to solve your problem, the `destroy_all` method is a class method. See the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy_all).

Please allow me to say that I believe you shouldn't use so many mocks on your tests. You can either let ActiveRecord do its thing, or structure your code differently to better encapsulate responsibilities between objects. ;)

Comment: Thanks you are correct it should be looking to receive(:destroy) not :destroy_all :-) I will update my code and error message

Comment: @gkats Yup I realised that this test does not belong in the controller but in a model test. Furthermore it belongs in the author model test as it is the author that has the has_many relation with books! So thats where the test should be!!!